# How to check for tabulator in files?

Tags: shell, grep

I would like to check a number of files for the existence of tab characters (ASCII 0x09) in them. (To assert that my sources are tab-free before committing them to repository.)

Preferably with standard tools. Of course, grep springs to mind, but apparently `grep "\t" file.txt` doesn't match...?!?

I am aware the answer is probably painfully simple, but I am at a loss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Of course, grep springs to mind, but apparently grep "\t" file.txt doesn't match...?!?

That searches for the literal character `t`. To search for a tab literal with `grep`, your shell will usually have a literal-insertion method. For example, in `bash`, use `grep $'\t' foo.txt`.

Comment: Yes, that works. I was unaware that \t, \n etc. didn't work as-is in shell commands.

Answer (score 1):

try with $'\t' instead of \t

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe grep understands the escape sequence `\t`. Try inserting a literal tab:

```
grep "<tab>" file.txt
```

Or, you can use awk instead.

Comment: The two answers above were correct. The "literal" tab you mention is interpreted by the bash, not inserted on the command line.

Comment: Like I said, you have to insert the literal tab. Most shells have a way to insert a literal tab. The sequence Ctrl-V, Tab in bash for example.

Comment: ...since the original post never mentioned what type of shell, I left this to you to insert the tab character in an appropriate way, which also differs if you are writing a script vs using the command line.